# Is each code page implemented as a subclass of System.Text.Encoding in .NET

Tags: c#, .net

Easy one here I think, can you confirm that each code page is implemented as a seperate and unique subclass of System.Text.Encoding in .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the context of your question, but yes, `Encoding.UTF8`, `Encoding.UTF16`, and anything that is returned from `Encoding.GetEncoding()` inherits from `System.Text.Encoding`. It cannot be any other way, since `Encoding.GetEncoding()` *returns* an `Encoding` instance, meaning the only thing it *can* do is return a subclass.

Comment: I mean there are hundreds of code pages, are there hundreds of sub classes or do some code pages share a class?

Comment: @Gary, oh right. No there is not a one-one mapping of code pages to classes. Many of the code pages are driven by a simple table mapping of bytes to unicode code points, so they would all share the same subclass of `Encoding`, but just with a different mapping table.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through Reflector, there's only a handful of classes that are subclasses of System.Text.Encoding.

Public:

- System.Text.ASCIIEncoding
- System.Text.UnicodeEncoding
- System.Text.UTF32Encoding
- System.Text.UTF7Encoding
- System.Text.UTF8Encoding

Internal:

- System.Text.Base64Encoding
- System.Text.BinHexEncoding
- System.Text.EncodingNLS
- System.Xml.Ucs4Encoding

The GetEncoding() method uses variations of each of these in order to give back the other hundreds of codepages supported.

Comment: when i run Console.WriteLine(Encoding.GetEncoding("Korean").GetType().ToString()); i get "System.Text.DBCSCodePageEncoding" output on the console

Comment: Doh! I didn't look far enough. There are quite a few more subclasses that subclass even more!

Answer (score 0):

No. Some encodings are supported natively by the .NET Framework (listed below) and these have their own subclasses. Any other code page is stored as a property of the object returned by `GetEncoding()`[1]  and support is provided by the underlying operating system.

The native (to .NET Framework) encodings are:

- `ASCIIEncoding`
- `UTF7Encoding`
- `UTF8Encoding`
- `UnicodeEncoding` (uses UTF-16)
- `UTF32Encoding`

(Information from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.aspx)

1: For non-native code pages this is potentially a subclass of `Encoding`, but I haven't checked. The documentation linked below seems to suggest that an instance of `Encoding` is used.